# Mirror requests from cloudrun service to other cloudrun service

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm currently working on a project where we are using Google Cloud. Within the Cloud we are using `CloudRun` to provide our services. One of these services is rather complex and has many different configuration options. To validate how these configurations affect the quality of the results and also to evaluate the quality of changes to the service, I would like to proceed as follows:

- in addition to the existing service I deploy another instance of the service which contains the changes
- I mirror all incoming requests and let both services process them, only the responses from the initial service are returned, but the responses from both services are stored

This allows me to create a detailed evaluation of the differences between the two services without having to provide the user with potentially worse responses.

For the implementation I have setup a NGINX which mirrors the requests. This is also deployed as a CloudRun service. This now accepts all requests and takes care of the authentication. The original service and the mirrored version have been configured in such a way that they can only be accessed internally and should therefore be accessed via a VPC network.

I have tried all possible combinations for the configuration of these parts but I always get 403 or 502 errors.

I have tried setting the NGINX service to the HTTP and HTTPS routes from the service, and I have tried all the VPC Connector settings. When I set the ingress from the service to `ALL` it works perfectly if I configure the service with HTTPS and port 443 in NGINX. As soon as I set the ingress to `Internal` I get errors with HTTPS -> 403 and with HTTP -> 502.

Does anyone have experience in this regard and can give me tips on how to solve this problem? Would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Cloud Run service are internally accessible (ingress control set to internal only), you need to perform your request from your VPC.

Therefore, as you perfectly did, you plugged a serverless VPC connector on your NGINX service.

The set up is correct. Now, why it works when you route ALL the egress traffic and not only the private traffic to your VPC connector?

In fact, Cloud Run is a public resource, with a public URL, and even if you set the ingress to internal. This param say "the traffic must come to the VPC" and not say "I'm plugged to the VPC with a private IP".

So, to go to your VPC and access a public ressource (Your cloud run services), you need to route ALL the traffic to your VPC, even the public one.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this response. Thank you for the explanation. Your answer confirms that my settings and configurations are correct. I do not understand what can not work and will look again for errors. I've seen that 8.8.8.8 is configured as DNS within my NGINX - maybe this is the problem because it can't resolve those internal cloudrun urls.

Comment: Be sure that you have a route (in Cloud Route) in 0.0.0.0 with the internet gateway as next hop.

Comment: Yes, the wrongly configured DNS server from NGINX caused my problems. Now everything is working! Thans for the support!